# Javafx Scenebuilder preview not matching actual scene

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

When I preview my form inside the Scene builder preview window [(Window in preview mode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFTkB.jpg) option everything is laid out perfectly like I want it and it is a good size. When I actually run the program [(what actually is shown)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TY2H.jpg) and click on my button to open this new form, only about 1/4 of my labels and buttons are actually shown unless I make it full screen and everything is far more spaced out than it should be. Anyway advice to fix this?

`

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <children>
  <VBox layoutY="-5.0" prefHeight="811.0" prefWidth="1058.0" spacing="15.0">
     <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="301.0" prefWidth="488.0" spacing="20.0">
           <children>
              <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="These are the available options for a 7 day cruise">
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="30.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Interior room ticket $765" />
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ocean view ticket $810" />
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Balcony ticket $1090" />
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Suite ticket $1560">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
              </RadioButton>
              <Label text="*Prices shown are prices per person">
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="24.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
           </children>
           <padding>
              <Insets top="20.0" />
           </padding>
        </VBox>
        <HBox prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="1895.0" spacing="30.0">
           <children>
              <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="VIP discount" />
              <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Prepaid gratitude" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <Label text="Prepaid activites that can be attended by both guests">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="30.0" />
           </font>
           <padding>
              <Insets top="75.0" />
           </padding>
        </Label>
        <HBox prefHeight="314.0" prefWidth="1895.0">
           <children>
              <VBox prefHeight="419.0" prefWidth="922.0" spacing="20.0">
                 <children>
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Free Internet" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Couples massage" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Horse back riding excursion" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fitness Classes" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox prefHeight="477.0" prefWidth="942.0" spacing="20.0">
                 <children>
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Casino Games" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Watch a show at the theatre" />
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Game Show" />
                    </children>
                  <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="25.0" />
                 </padding>
              </VBox>
           </children>
        </HBox>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Calculate total price" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

`

[Main Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuPNR.jpg)

Comment: Could you link screenshots of what you and what happens. Also add the code you use to load and set this fxml/

Comment: Most probably Ithe problem is that your'e defining the dimensions of the parent container and then setting the above view

Comment: I've added screenshots to my original post. @th3sp33dst3r

Comment: Are you setting your `Stage` width in the code?

Comment: You are manualy setting a lot of widths and heights. If you do that you need to make sure they add up the their parents width and height.

Comment: I also find it hard to believe your preview looks like that if you got the root node set to -> `prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0"`

Comment: Try `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 700));` and use the answer below.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for working with me, this is my first time creating a GUI

Answer (score 0):

I went in and got rid of most of the manual sizes. I would also set the `PrimaryStage` width to 800 and height to 700 and not allow resizing. Test this out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="700.0" maxWidth="800.0" minHeight="700.0" minWidth="800.0" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <children>
  <VBox layoutY="-5.0" spacing="15.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" spacing="20.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
           <children>
              <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="These are the available options for a 7 day cruise">
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Interior room ticket $765">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </RadioButton>
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ocean view ticket $810">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </RadioButton>
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Balcony ticket $1090">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </RadioButton>
              <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Suite ticket $1560">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </padding>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                     </font>
              </RadioButton>
           </children>
        </VBox>
            <VBox>
               <children>
              <Label text="*Prices shown are prices per person">
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="16.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <HBox spacing="30.0">
                 <children>
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="VIP discount">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Prepaid gratitude">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </CheckBox>
                 </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </padding>
              </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="20.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
              <Label text="Prepaid activites that can be attended by both guests" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                 <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <HBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                 <children>
                    <VBox spacing="20.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <children>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Free Internet">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Couples massage">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Horse back riding excursion">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fitness Classes">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                       </children>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </padding>
                    </VBox>
                    <VBox spacing="20.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <children>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Casino Games">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Watch a show at the theatre">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Game Show">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                          </children>
                        <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="25.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </VBox>
                 </children>
              </HBox>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="30.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </VBox>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" text="Calculate total price" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="15.0" left="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="15.0" />
   </padding>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]

Comment: How does your `Main` class look?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my main class